# Find $a>o$ so that the tangent line to the graph of $f(x)=x^2e^{-x}$ on $x=a$ goes through the origin.

Tags: calculus, exponential-function, tangent-line

I believe these are the first steps:
$$
f´(x)=2xe^{-x}-x^2 e^x$$
$$f´(a)= 2ae^{-a}-a^2 e^a
$$
Since it goes through the origin, the tangent line on $a$ is given by:
$$y-0 = f´(a)(x-0)...$$ but I don´t know what goes next in order to find the value of $a$...
Thanks to everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made a mistake:
$$
\begin{split}
f(x) &= x^2 e^{-x}\\
f'(x) &= 2xe^{-x}-x^2e^{-x}\\
f'(a) &= \frac{2a-a^2}{e^a}.
\end{split}
$$
As you mention, you need to have the tangent line at $a$ go through the origin, so it must have equation
$$
y = f'(a)x,
$$
In other words, $L(a) = f'(a)a$. But since it is a tangent line, it must pass through $(a, f(a))$, i.e. $L(a) = f(a)$, so you end up with
$$
f(a) = L(a) = f'(a)a.
$$
Hence, you must solve
$$
\frac{a^2}{e^a} = \frac{2a-a^2}{e^a}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

As the tangent at $x=a$ also passes through the point $(a, f(a))$, you simply have to find the positive root(s) of the equation
$$f(a)=af'(a).$$
Explicitly this equation becoes here
$$a^2\mathrm e^{-a}=a(2a-a^2)\mathrm e^{-a}\iff a^2=a^2(2-a).$$